# c++ stucts cant be accessed outside the if statement

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, for-loop, struct

The goal is to have the user input some movie information for two movies.
Then two functions output the movies data
The problem is when I try to use the functions outside the if statements they cant be accssed anymore.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct MovieData // the stuct
{
    string Title,  // required varibles
        Director;
    int yearReleased,
        runTime;

    MovieData(string TITLE, string  DIRECTOR, int YearReleased, int RunTime)  // constructors 
    {
        Title = TITLE;
        Director = DIRECTOR;
        yearReleased = YearReleased;
        runTime = RunTime;
    }
    string getTitle() // getters
    { return Title; }
    string getDirector()
    { return Director; }
    int getYear()
    { return yearReleased; }
    int getLength()
    { return runTime; }
};

void printMovie1(MovieData movieprint1) // fucntion that outputs movie 1
{
    cout << "Title of movie " << movieprint1.getTitle() << endl;
    cout << "Director is " << movieprint1.getDirector()<< endl;
    cout << "Movie release year " << movieprint1.getYear()<< endl;
    cout << "Movie length " << movieprint1.getLength() << endl;
}

void printMovie2(MovieData movieprint2) // function that outputs movie 2
{
    cout << "Title of movie " << movieprint2.getTitle() << endl;
    cout << "Director is " << movieprint2.getDirector() << endl;
    cout << "Movie release year " << movieprint2.getYear() << endl;
    cout << "Movie length " << movieprint2.getLength() << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string Title, // local varibles
        Director;
    int yearReleased,
        runTime;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // forward loop to enter movie info
    {
        cout << "Please enter the movie " << (i + 1) << " title ";
        getline(cin, Title);

        cout << "Now the director ";
        getline(cin, Director);

        cout << "What year was " << Title << " releasted ";
        cin >> yearReleased;

        cout << "Lastly the length ";
        cin >> runTime;
        cin.ignore();

        if (i == 0)
        {
            MovieData movie1(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);
            // I know function works when placed here
            // printMovie1(movie1); 
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
          MovieData  movie2(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);
         // I know function works when placed here
          // printMovie2(movie2);
        }
    }
    // these functions now dont work
    enter code hereprintMovie1(movie1);
    printMovie2(movie2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `movie1` and `movie2` variables are declared in the scope of the if block. If you want to use them outside, declare them outside.

Answer (score 0):

You're having a **scope issue**
When you write :

```
  if (i == 0)
        {
            MovieData movie1(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);
            // movie1 starts living

        } // Aaand he's dead.
```

Your movie1 lives only inside thoses brackets. That's exactly why you must declare `movie1` in the same scope you want to print them.

Another thing, since it's `c++`, try looking up how `class` work, i think in your overall approch to the problem `class` would do a much better work than `struct`.

And by the way, why not put the function `printMovie1()` inside your struct ?

Oh, and you don't need 2 print function, since they **do the exact same job.**

Try for example to call :

```
printMovie1(movie1);
printMovie1(movie2);
```

See ? it'll be the same output. Keep up the work, you're getting close to a good thing !

Comment: I agree that a `class` would suit it better (simply concept-wise) but there isn't actually any difference between `class` and `struct` apart from that the former defaults its members to `private` and the latter defaults its members to `public`

Comment: @Kvothe I said that only because he did declare getters to his struct, thus my reflexion. But yeah, thanks for making clear the scope difference between class & struct !

Comment: Don't forget to comment when you downvote, if you think there's things to be improved in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the `scope` of obects. You have declared both the objects inside their `if` statements. To put it simply, an object always exists only inside the immediate block (think `{` and `}`) that it is declared in.

In your case :

```
if (i == 0)
    {
        MovieData movie1(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);
        //movie1 exists only inside this if statement.
    }
  //no movie1 from here on
```

So yo gotta do something like :

```
MovieData movie1;

if (i == 0)
    {
       movie1 = MovieData(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);

    }
//movie1 is accessible here. yay
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MovieData lives only inside the scope of the brackets. Once you exit the outer scope, you can't access it anymore. 
You could fix it declaring your variable outside the scope.

```
    MovieData  movie; //default construction
    if (i == 0)
    {
        movie = MovieData(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);
        // I know function works when placed here
        // printMovie1(movie1); 
    }
    else if (i == 1)
    {
      movie= MovieData(Title, Director, yearReleased, runTime);
     // I know function works when placed here
      // printMovie2(movie2);

    }
    //you can now use movie
```

Answer (score -2):

C/C++ uses block-local variables. For the sake of interest, this is not universal among programming languages; R and JavaScript are notable languages that use function-local variables. In other words, in R and JavaScript, when you declare (in JavaScript) or assign (in R) a local variable, it becomes part of the function's "activation object" (in JavaScript) or "evaluation environment" (in R). Subsequently it can be accessed from anywhere inside the function, even outside the scope of the declaration/assignment that created it.

Since you're using C++, you have to be careful about your blocks. You can't declare a variable inside a block and then access it outside of the block. This is enforced by the compiler. Thus, to solve your problem, you have to move your declarations of `movie1` and `movie2` out of the heavily nested blocks and into the outermost block inside which those variables will be accessed. You're going to have to define a nullary constructor and assignment method to allow this to work (since you have to branch on the assignment), or alternatively you could allocate dynamically (i.e. with `new`) inside the if-branches, in which case you would call the constructor at that time.